# Detecting ctrl+v on key press

Tags: c#, .net, keypress

I am using text box `keypress` event to handle only selected inputs. Basically the `textbox` allow user to input values where it can be calculated.

i.e. you can type `(5*5)- (10/5)`.

The current method check like `Convert.ToChar("*")==e.KeyChar` etc...

At the moment it doesn't allow user to copy paste values.

Is there anyway that can detect the `ctrl+v` on `keypress` event?

**Update**

What I am doing at the moment

```
   static IEnumerable<char> ValidFiancialCharacters
       {
           get
           {
               if(_validFiancialCharacters==null)
               {
                 _validFiancialCharacters = new List<char>();

                 _validFiancialCharacters.Add(Convert.ToChar("0"));
                 _validFiancialCharacters.Add(Convert.ToChar("1"));
                 _validFiancialCharacters.Add(Convert.ToChar("2"));
                 // till 9 and
                  _validFiancialCharacters.Add(Convert.ToChar("+"));
                  _validFiancialCharacters.Add(Convert.ToChar("-"));
                  _validFiancialCharacters.Add(Convert.ToChar("/"));
                  //and some other
                }
                return _validFiancialCharacters;
             }
       }


 public static bool ValidateInput(KeyPressEventArgs e)
   {
       if (ValidFiancialCharacters.Any(chr => chr == e.KeyChar))
       {
           e.Handled = false;
       }
       else
       {
           e.Handled = true;
       }
       return e.Handled;
   }
```

And in the keypress

```
   private void txtRate_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        NumberExtension.ValidateInput(e);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you working at the level of keys at all? Can't you just evaluate `textbox.Text` on change, leaving the responsibility for keys and copy paste with the standard textbox which handles all that?

Comment: I am restricting user to input some values. Allow only certain values

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to handle both, can be done using the similar approach

Have a look at [Key Codes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes). You can detect what ever the key been pressed

so..

Create a list containing all the inputs you need

```
 public List<int> KeyCodes = new List<int>() { 8, 17, 37, 39.....etc};
```

and use the `KeyDown` event and use [KeyEventArgs.SuppressKeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

```
private void Txt1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (KeyCodes.Contains(e.KeyValue) || (e.KeyCode==Keys.V && e.Control))
        e.SuppressKeyPress = false;
    else 
        e.SuppressKeyPress=true;
}
```

You might need to validate the copy pasted value in `leave event`, since user can paste anything!!!

Comment: There's a problem with `KeyDown` and `SuppressKeyPress` that if you want to allow only some specific keys, it will suppress all the other keys **on the form level**. e.g. Alt+F4

Answer (score 6):

Just look at the Modifiers propertie in you `KeyDown` or `KeyUp` event for `Keys.Control`

> **Modifiers** Gets the modifier flags for a KeyDown or KeyUp event. The flags indicate which combination of CTRL, SHIFT, and ALT keys was pressed.

### Sample

**KeyDown**

```
 this.myTextBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(myTextBox_KeyDown);

 private void myTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
      {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello world");
      }
  }
```

or **KeyUp**

```
 this.myTextBox.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(myTextBox_KeyUp);

 private void myTextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
      {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello world");
      }
  }
```

### Update

To allow only certain inputs you can use the `KeyPress` event.

```
this.myTextBox.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(this.myTextBox_KeyPress);

private void myTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    int i;
    if (int.TryParse(e.KeyChar.ToString(), out i) || 
        e.KeyChar == '(' ||
        e.KeyChar == ')' ||
        e.KeyChar == '.' ||
        e.KeyChar == '*' ||
        e.KeyChar == '+' ||
        e.KeyChar == '-' ||
        e.KeyChar == '/'
        // add some more)
    {

    } else e.Handled = true; // dont allow other inputs
}
```

### More Information

- [MSDN - KeyEventArgs Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MSDN - Control.KeyDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MSDN - Control.KeyUp Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi, thanks. But will i be able to perform the other check as I mentioned in question. it to allow certain characters only. Using the `keyup`?

Comment: I have both the events at the moment. So event it pass from `KeyDown` it fails from keypress

Comment: Yes, I know, but the problem I have is to allow only certain other characters along with `ctrl+v`. i.e. all the numbers, and some other input like `+,-,*` etc...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58688/discussion-between-popeye-the-sailor-man-and-dknaack).

Answer (score 3):

`KeyPress` event doesn't catch "Ctrl + V" for some reason. Use `KeyDown` event:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
    {
        //Ctrl + V
    }
}
```

or

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.V))
    {
        //Ctrl + V
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I need to allow only certain other characters along with ctrl+v. i.e. all the numbers, and some other input like +,-,* . Is it possible in keydown event?

Comment: No, you can't. You need to inherit your textbox, override `WndProc` and handle `Wm_Paste` message. Otherwise you can use `TextChanged` event to see what user has pasted/

Comment: No, I will handle the pasted value separately. But to allow type values like I mentioned earlier

Comment: @Popeyethesailorman That's what I told, you need to handle `Wm_Paste` and check what user is pasting, you may decide whether to allow it or not.

Answer (score 1):

The Ctrl+V sequence can be catched by KeyPressEvent. 
You just cannot check it by the following :

```
(Keys)e.KeyChar == Keys.V && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control <br>
```

You must use:

```
(int)e.KeyChar==22 && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control <br>
```

because the keybord generates the ASCII=22 (synchronous idle). 
The following example enables TextBox to accept +- amounts with comma separator and allows pasting by Ctrl+V

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!( char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) ||
         ((Keys)e.KeyChar == Keys.Back) ||
         (e.KeyChar == ',') ||
         (e.KeyChar == '-') ||
         ((int)e.KeyChar==22 && Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
        ))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if (e.KeyChar == ',' && base.Text.IndexOf(',') > 0)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use KeyDown or KeyUp, because the KeyPress event is not raised by the CTRL button but only by "character" buttons. If you use the KeyDown event you can detect `ctrl+v` by checking:

```
if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
{
    ...
}
```