# Restrict keypress in wpf textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, keypress, keyboard-events

I have TextBox in WPF where i need to fill the box only by pasting (ctrl +v) not by typing. So i need to restrict entire key press except ctrl+v. Since WPF is not having keypress event i am facing the problem to restrict the keypress

Comment: Well, I have not actually tried this out, but perhaps you could set a "key press" handler that will check the length of the input string. So If(input.length() > 1) // accept the input else // input = "";

Comment: @JohnAugust what if he pastes only 1 character at a time?

Comment: thank you bro but if i paste the content then the length will increase  and it will restrict the content

Comment: ...Ahh, yes, all very good points, especially if only one character is pasted.  In that case have a look at the "modifiers" property: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135505/detecting-ctrlv-on-key-press Then add that into the if statement check. So in other words, if you see if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control) Then accept the input, else input = "";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it WPF style and use ApplicationCommands.Paste and make the textbox readonly.

Comment: @jeevan_jk try and come back for help... it's not nice to have people code for you.

Comment: @Wouter Thank you much i have implemented it

Answer (score 1):

you can add this Key_Down handler to the textBox:

```
  private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.Key==Key.V)
       {
         //Logic here
       }
      else
        e.handled=true;
   }
```

Comment: here is wpf not winform

Answer (score 0):

Provided you don't allow `Right Click + Paste`, but only `Ctrl + V`, I would simply check for the Ctrl key modifier being pressed and prevent everything else.

Comment: Do it WPF style and use ApplicationCommands.Paste and make the textbox readonly.

Answer (score 0):

So try this:

```
 myTextBox.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(myTextBox_KeyDown);

 private void myTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
      if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
      {
            input = myTextBox.Text;
      }
      else
      {
            input = "";
      }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Name="Policy_text">
   <TextBox.CommandBindings>
       <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Paste" CanExecute="PasteCommand_CanExecute" Executed="PasteCommand_Executed" />
   </TextBox.CommandBindings>
</Textbox>
```

and in code behind

```
private void PasteCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = Clipboard.ContainsText();
    }

private void PasteCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Policy_text.Paste();
    }
```